# C++ won't recognize my for loop

Tags: c++

I'm probably just missing something really simple that's going over my head but when I run my program it just skips my for loop entirely, why?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //user input
    int largest=0, num, i=0;
    cout << "Please enter 10 numbers to find the largest one" << endl;
    for (i=0, i < 10; i++;)
    {
        cout << "Enter number " << i+1 <<":";
        cin >> num;
        if (num > largest)
        largest = num;

    }
    cout << "The largest number is: " << largest;
return 0;
```

}

Comment: `for (i=0, i < 10; i++;)` => `for (i=0; i < 10; i++)`

Comment: `for (i=0, i < 10; i++;)` => `for (i=0; i < 10; i++)`

Comment: haha nice dupe comments ;)

Comment: Check the commas and semicolons in the for

Comment: or `i++` ==> `++i` and have the loop run billions of times :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(/*Initialize*/; /*Evaluate*/ ;/*update iterater*/);
```

using the above you have `i++` in the Evaluate section of the for loop.

```
0 == false
```

try it like this :

```
for (i=0 ; i < 10; i++)
```

Comment: I knew it was something really dumb like that. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax is wrong: for loop should have the form:

```
for ( init; condition; increment )
```

Note the clauses are separated by `;`. But you wrote:

```
for (i=0, i < 10; i++;)
```

With a `,` instead of the first `;`.

So you have `i=0, i < 10` as your `init`, `i++` as your `condition`, and nothing as your `increment`.

Therefore, when your loop runs, first you set `i=0`, then you evaluate `i < 10` and throw away the result.

Then you check the "condition", which is `i++` - which returns `i` before the increment, which is `0`, which means `false`, and your loop therefore does not execute.

Instead, you meant to write:

```
for (i=0; i < 10; i++)
```

Which would function as you expect.